# Decoding gb18030 to UTF8 in C#

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a text file, the contents if open in notepad shows:

```
Ê¸³ßÓÀ¼ª
```

If I drag it to chrome browser, it automatically decode and display correctly as

```
矢尺永吉
```

After a bit of research, the code in the file is encoded with gb18030.  I am attempting to do the conversion in C#.  Below is my code:

```
public static string codeCovert(string s)
    {
        Encoding gb18 = Encoding.GetEncoding("gb18030");
        Encoding Utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;

        byte[] gbcode = gb18.GetBytes(s);

        return Utf8.GetString(gbcode);      
    }
```

And this still gives a whole bunch of wrong characters.  Can anyone help please? Thanks.

Comment: Your string is already damaged at the point of `string s`. You must read the file with the encoding, it's too late otherwise.

Comment: so during debug, I can see that string is "Ê¸³ßÓÀ¼ª".  How do I tell if this is too late? Thanks.

Comment: Because you did not specify encoding when you read your file with your C# code. That is how you know it's too late.

Comment: Well, the source of code was not exactly coming from a text file, just for test purpose.  These are actually Idv3 in a mp3. And those are stored as string.  I need a function to be able to convert  string "Ê¸³ßÓÀ¼ª" into string "矢尺永吉".  ....any thoughts? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Any file is a sequence of bytes. Read the chunk as a `byte[]` and pass it to `gb18.GetString`.

Comment: @GSerg You got it right.  If I read byte directly, my method works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method takes in a `string` and returns another `string` which does not make sense. `System.String` is a "vector" of UTF-16 code units.

You should do:

```
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

// ...

  var str = File.ReadAllText(@"path\file.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("GB18030"));
```

While `str` is in memory, it has the value `"矢尺永吉"`. It cannot be "UTF-8" when it is a .NET string in memory. You can save it to another file, of course:

```
  File.WriteAllText(@"path\otherfile.txt", str, Encoding.UTF8);
```

---

Edit: In newer versions of .NET, you need to do:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

before you can use `Encoding.GetEncoding("GB18030")`.

Comment: well, except that text file is just an example....the situation I am dealing with is a MP3 Idv2....using a library to read it get me a string.....I wonder if there is a method can actually convert a string Ê¸³ßÓÀ¼ª into a string 矢尺永吉, knowing the encoding method.....I could be digging out how to read idv2 tag in byte too....

Comment: `"Ê¸³ßÓÀ¼ª"` is corrupted. It is a Unicode string consisting of the characters you see. It is not GB 18030. A value of `System.String` cannot be in GB 18030, and it also cannot be in UTF-8. Trying to make a method that translates between such two `string` is wrong. If you mean binary data, use `byte[]`.

Comment: I see.  I will try to get the byte directly from MP3 Idv2.  And will let you know.

Comment: What is `Encoding.Default.WebName` on your system? Windows-1252? Most likely the bytes have been mis-interpreted as some western codepage. Then you can use `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetBytes("Ê¸³ßÓÀ¼ª")` to try to recover the bytes, and then `Encoding.GetEncoding("GB18030").GetString( … )` on that to get the string. "Your way." But I do not recommend it.